# SQL select specific fields in JOIN query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i'm writing an Android app and i've run into a bit of a roadblock involving databases.  the way Android handles databases, i cannot refer to names in the result set by the usual 'tablename.colname' method, so this presents a huge issue when any tables in the database contain the same column name.  what further complicates the issue, is that any table that is used by a ViewAdapter to display the data to the user (as in my application), must contain a field named "_id" as an autoincrement primary key int.  therefore, some tables MUST have identical column names.  however, to avoid this, it is possible to use an "AS" clause in a statement to rename the value in question.  however, i'm using a rather long statement and i don't know how to limit the columns returned on a JOINed table.  what i have is this, and it's completely illegal in android due to the 'tablename.colname' references.  i actually added the table names in to make the statement more readable, but i can't use them:

```
SELECT call._id AS android_call_id,
call.phone,
call.time,
call.duration
call.duration_billed
call.pending
call.call_id
call.job_id
FROM call

LEFT OUTER JOIN phone ON call.phone_number=phone.phone

LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON job._id=call.job_id

WHERE call.pending=1 ORDER BY job._id
```

but what i need, is to rename the job._id to something else using an "AS" statement, same as with the 'call._id' field in the first part of the query.  how do i achieve this renaming in a JOIN?

edit:

progress so far.  i think i've worked out the syntax errors, but i get another runtime error "no such column 'job._id', which may be related to @Tom H. comment

edit 2:

turns out Tom was right, and i adjusted accordingly, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT call._id AS android_call_id,
call.phone,
call.time,
call.duration,
call.duration_billed,
call.pending,
call.call_id,
call.job_id,
job._id AS android_job_id,
job.job_name,
job.job_number
FROM call

LEFT OUTER JOIN phone ON call.phone_number=phone.phone

LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON job._id=call.job_id

WHERE call.pending=1 ORDER BY job._id
```

error:

```
05-24 16:50:37.561: ERROR/Minutemaid - Service(7705): oops: ambiguous column name: call._id: , while compiling: SELECT call._id AS android_call_id,call.phone_number,call.time,call.duration,call.duration_billed,call.pending,call.call_id,call.job_id,job._id AS android_job_id,job.job_name,job.job_number FROM call LEFT OUTER JOIN phone ON call.phone_number=phone.phone LEFT OUTER JOIN call ON call.job_id=job._id WHERE call.pending=1 ORDER BY job._id
```

Comment: the column aliases are for the output, not for the join.. you need to use the real column names there.

Comment: @Fosco i realize that... i don't think you understand the question...

Comment: You don't have any columns from the job table listed at all in your SELECT clause. The Android application shouldn't even be able to see them. I'm not clear on exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Does it help if you change `ORDER BY job._id to ORDER BY call.job_id` ?

Comment: @moonlight, rather than editing @benoit's answer with your attempted code, you should incorporate that code (and error message) into your question. :)

Comment: From your error message: [snip]`LEFT OUTER JOIN call ON call.job_id=job._id`[snip]: your outer join there should be to `job` rather than to `call`

Comment: You are accidentally outer joining `call` to itself, hence the 'ambiguous column name' error - if you intended to do a self-join, you'd need to alias the separate occurrences of the table in the query.

Comment: @slothrop where did you get that snip?  it's nowhere in my code above.

Comment: @moonlightcheese - it's in the error message you posted - scroll nearly all the way to the right.

Comment: got it.  the code above didn't match the android code (which i abbreviated in SQL to get better answers).  that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply use `AS` to alias all of the `tablename.columnname` references to unique names in the result set?

Comment: apparently so.  was just confused on the syntax to get what i'm after.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a VIEW that restricts columns selectable in a table and assigns another name to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try massaging the table names before you join them by using sub-queries with AS in the FROM clause. For example:

```
select c_phone, c_id, p_id
from (select id as c_id, phone as c_phone, phone_number as c_phone_number, ... from call) as c
left outer join (select id as p_id, phone as p_phone, ... ) as p
  on c_phone_number = p_phone
...
```

If the limitation is just that you can't use table names to distinguish between columns but can use correlation names then simpler is:

```
select c.id, c.phone, p.id as "p_id" from ... call c join phone p
```

Comment: aaaahhh... that makes aliases with subqueries a lot more clear.  thanks for the example.